# DMA memory block is not takeing input

Tags: memory

So I am trying to write a symple program that takes an input in the form of an int and adds it to a block of memory. Then the user can choose to input another number and keep doing this for as long as they want. Whenever I run the program if I only choose to input 1 number it displays the wrong number when the list is outputted but if I try to enter multiple numbers the program crashes. Any input or advice would be apreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int i,  j;
    int *list;
    char loop;

    j = 1;

        //alocates memory
        list = calloc(j, sizeof(int));
        if(list == NULL)
        {

            printf("Sorry the memory could not be alocated\n");
            return 0;

        } //end if


    //this is where the user can enter the elements of the list
    for(i = 0;i < j;i++)
    {

        //instructs the user to enter a value
        printf("Enter elemint %d of the number list\n", j);

        //stores value entered
        scanf("%d", & *(list+i));

        printf("Do you want to enter another number?\n Y yes\n N no\n");

        //checks input
        do
        {

            //gets input
            scanf("%1s", &loop);

        } //end do while
        while(loop != 'Y' && loop != 'y' && loop != 'N' && loop != 'n');

        if(loop == 'Y' || loop == 'y')
        {

            j++;

            //reallocates memory
            list = realloc(list, j*sizeof(int));

        } //end if
        else if(loop == 'N' || loop == 'n')
        {

            printf("Okay list complete\n");

        } //end else if
        else
        {

            printf("ERROR");
            return 0;

        } //end else

    } //end for

    printf("You entered\n");

    //prints the elemints of the list
    for(i = 0 ; i < j ; i++)
    {

        printf("%d ", *(list+i));

    } //end for

    free(list);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT
I have figured out the problem but my solution is kind of odd. So all I did is initialise my index variable i inside of the for loops instead of at the start of main.
Also yes there are more comments and I have fixed formatting issues but they don't matter in terms of the code

```
/*
    Description
This program takes input from the user by useing a resizeable list and then displays the list
    Author
Paul Geoghegan
    Date
25/01/20
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int j;
    int *list;
    char loop;

    j = 1;

    //alocates memory
    list = calloc(j, sizeof(int));
    //checks if memory has been allocated correctly
    if(list == NULL)
    {

        printf("Sorry the memory could not be alocated\n");
        return 0;

    } //end if

    //this is where the user can enter the elements of the list
    for(int i = 0;i < j;i++)
    {

        //instructs the user to enter a value
        printf("Enter elemint %d of the number list\n", j);

        //stores value entered
        scanf("%d", &*(list+i));

        printf("Do you want to enter another number?\n Y yes\n N no\n");

        //checks input
        do
        {

            //gets input
            scanf("%1s", &loop);

        } //end do while
        while(loop != 'Y' && loop != 'y' && loop != 'N' && loop != 'n');

        if(loop == 'Y' || loop == 'y')
        {

            //increases j for use in reallocateing the memory block
            j++;

            //reallocates memory
            list = realloc(list, j*sizeof(int));

        } //end if
        else if(loop == 'N' || loop == 'n')
        {

            printf("Okay list complete\n");

        } //end else if
        else
        {

            printf("ERROR");
            return 0;

        } //end else

    } //end for

    printf("You entered\n");

    //prints the elemints of the list
    for(int i = 0 ; i < j ; i++)
    {

        printf("%d ", *(list+i));

    } //end for

    //frees up memory and ends program
    free(list);
    return 0;
} //end program
```